# jQuery clone question

Tags: jquery, json, clone, fade

I have a problem.

I use this code:

```
$( '#wall_msg').clone( true ).insertAfter( '#wall_msg' );
```

What can I do to set the ID for the clone and I need to fade the new item in with `$.getJSON` in jQuery.

I hope for help. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("#wall_msg").clone(true)
  .attr("id", "newid")
  .hide()
  .insertAfter("#wall_msg")
  .fadeIn();
```